# Drive not showing up in EC2 Console, but shows up when I do lsblk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've inherited a sever that lives on EC2. When I do the following:

```
lsblk
```

I get:

```
xvda    202:0    0    40G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    40G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    30G  0 disk /home/dbt
xvdd    202:48   0   100G  0 disk /home/rails/drawer
xvdf    202:80   0    15G  0 disk
```

When I go to the EC2 Console, EBS, Volumes, I only see:

```
... 40 GiB ..../dev/sda1 (attached)
... 100 GiB ..../dev/sdd (attached)
... 15 GiB ..../dev/sdf (attached)
```

Why isn't /dev/sdb showing up in the console? Could it be that when the server was created, this was the hard disk that came with the server, and so it does not show up as an EBS volume?

Comment: try "sudo fdisk -l " and "sudo parted -l" to check what is /dev/xvdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably an ephemeral disk. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html.